# Every measurable set in $X \times Y$ is contained in a measurable rectangle

Tags: measure-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are any two sets (not necessarily subsets of the
same space), the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ is the set of all ordered
pairs $(x,y)$, where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. Thus, for instance, if $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$, we shall call the set $E = A \times B$ (a subset of $X \times Y$) a rectangle
and we shall refer to the component sets $A$ and $B$ as its sides.

In our context the word "class" should be understood as a set of sets. So the class of measurable rectangles refers to the set of measurable rectangles. So I want to use the fact that a rectangle $A \times B$ in the Cartesian product of two measurable spaces $(X, S)$ and $(Y, T)$, (where $S$ and $T$ are $\sigma$-rings of subsets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively), is measurable if $ A \in S $ and $ B \in T $.

I am reading the Measure Theory book by Paul Halmos, I have found this.
Exercise (6) Section 33.

If $(X,S)$ and $(Y,T)$ are measurable spaces, then every  measurable set in $X \times Y$ is contained in a measurable rectangle.

My idea is the following:

the class of all those sets which way be covered by a measurable rectangle is a $\sigma$-Ring.

I think this class contains every measurable set of $ X\times Y$, on the other hand if I test that it is a $ \sigma $-Ring I have finished

Comment: I probably don’t understand the question, but isn’t $X \times Y$ a measurable rectangle containing any set?

Comment: You're right! but we are not certain that $X \times Y$ is a measurable rectangle

Comment: Then what is a measurable rectangle?

Comment: According to Halmos: "A measurable space is a set $X$ and $\sigma$-ring $S$ of subsets of $X$ with the property that  $\bigcup S = X.$"

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Can't you just verify the claim in the hint Halmos gives for the exercise? "(Hint: the class of all those sets which may be covered by a measurable rectangle is a $\sigma-$ring"?

Comment: The question is about sigma algebras not sigma rings. Any sigma algebra on $X$ contains $X$ by definition.

Comment: The question is about measurable spaces, which Halmos defines in terms of sigma rings, as quoted in these comments.

Comment: When you say measurable set of $X \times Y$, what is the $\sigma$-algebra here? If it is the natural $\sigma$-algebra (generated by $A \times B, A \in S, B \in T$), the answer is trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halmos develops the Measure theory based on **$\sigma$-rings**. Measurable set of $X\times Y$ means sets in product  **$\sigma$-ring**, that is generated by $A \times B$, $A \in S$, $B \in T$ where $S$ and $T$ are **$\sigma$-rings**.  In general, $X\times Y$ may not be a measurable rectangle.

Your idea on how to solve exercise 6 (section 33) is correct. It is exactly the way to go.

Here is a detailed solution to exercise 6 in section 33:

Let $$C=\{ E \subseteq X\times Y : \textrm{ there are } A\in S, B \in T \textrm{ such that } E \subseteq A\times B\}$$

Just checking the definition of $\sigma$-ring, it is immediate that $C$ is $\sigma$-ring.

It is also immediate that for all $A\in S, B \in T$, $A\times B \in C$.

So $C$ is a $\sigma$-ring and all measurable rectangles are in $C$.

Since $S \times T$ is the smallest $\sigma$-ring  having all  measurable rectangles,
we have $S \times T\subseteq C$. It means that every measurable sets of $X \times Y$  is contained in a measurable rectangle.